# Removing an element of a class that has an element that is list of another class

Tags: java, list, class, removeall

I have this two classes:

```
public class Table {
    String tableName;
    private List <Column> columns;
}

public class Column {
    String columnName;
}
```

And I created two lists of `Table` class:

```
List<Table> table1 = new ArrayList<Table>();
List<Table> table2 = new ArrayList<Table>()
```

And got the values for this lists from Oracle DB.

```
table1 = tableDao.ListTabColumns();
table2 = tableDao.ListTabColumns();
```

I Tryied `removeAll` and do not works.

```
table1.removeAll(table2);
```

And... `Set<Table>` and `removeAll` and does not work too.

```
Set<Table> t1 = new HashSet<Table>(table1);
Set<Table> t2 = new HashSet<Table>(table2);
t1.removeAll(t2);
```

And I tryied to use `contains` for each element of `table1` in `table2` and nothing.

Only way that works was  inner loops of each element of List and after inner loop of each element of List.

```
for(Table t : table1) {
    for(Table x : table2) {
        System.out.println(t.getTableName());
        for(Column c : x.getColumn()) {
            for (Column d : t.getColumn()) {
                // Something to display if not contain any equals.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I do not think that is the best way to do this.
Someone can help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you override `equals` and `hashCode` functions in `Column` object?

Answer (score 0):

I did this overrid and works fine:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
         return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Column))
         return false;
    Column c = (Column) obj;
    return this.columnName == null ? false : this.columnName.equals(c.columnName);
    }

@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.columnName == null ? 0 : this.columnName.hashCode();
    }
```

Thanks so much, **Michał Piątkowski**!